# Focus TextArea after Drag/Drop in ExtJS 4.0.5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In my ExtJS Application, the user can drag a row/item from a GridPanel to a TextArea and its content is inserted at the current cursor index of the TextArea.

As soon as I start to drag the GridItem, the TextArea obviously loses focus. 
When dropping the item, I want to refocus the TextArea (and set the caret/cursor to the old position). I tried calling the focus() method of the TextArea component in the "Drop Event" like so:

```
notifyDrop: function (ddSource, e, data) {
   //all the insertion stuff which works fine

   var textarea = Ext.getCmp("textAreaID");
   textarea.focus(); //doesn't work
}
```

When I call textarea.focus() from the browser console it works fine, so my guess is that it's the wrong event to call it from.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try calling the focus in a setTimeout with a 1ms delay.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Worked, thanks! I tried it before using the delay parameter of the focus() method but that didn't work. setTimeout worked though.

Comment: They should be more or less the same, that's weird.